# Add local jar to Maven project which will be deployed to Openshift

Tags: java, maven, openshift

I've created local library which want to use in another local project, both are maven projects. As I read in the Internet I've published project to local maven repository and used it as maven dependency. The problem is that this is local and I want to deploy this project to OpenShift where application is built again by server. Of course project doesn't compile becouse of local dependency (server doesn't see this dependency). How to solve this problem? Should I add *.jar to libs dir and connect this in that way? But how? I haven't found how can I do it in maven project.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem but I wanted to solve this in a different way. However application builds on OpenShift server correctly. Problem solved by installing jar in local OpenShift repo using this command:

```
mvn install:install-file \
    -Dfile=multiplayergame-java-common-libs-0.9.jar \
    -DgroupId=pepuch \
    -DartifactId=multiplayergame-java-common-libs \
    -Dversion=0.9 \
    -Dpackaging=jar`
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. I ran a similar command on the openShift server then referenced it in my pom.xml and it built correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar solution outlined in an OpenShift Knowledge Base here:  https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1040-using-your-own-jar-files-in-a-java-application

Hope that helps.  Please feel free to chime in on the OpenShift Forums as well.