# Openshift : how to deploy multiple modules?

Tags: maven, openshift, redhat

I developed my sample project with two modules. `myapp-core` for repository purpose and `myapp-front` for public use. I made both projects with **maven** default archetype. `myapp-core` was packed as ***jar*** and `myapp-front` as ***war***.
I added `myapp-core` as dependency for `myapp-front` in *pom.xml* of `myapp-front` as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycom.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is working fine at my local machine *(run with eclipse , tomcat)* . I had tried to host my sample app to [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) but I don't know exactly how to deploy both of my projects. So , I googled and just only deploy `myapp-front`. 
Now I got error

> remote: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myapp-front: Could
>   not resolve dependencies for project myapp-front:myapp-front:war:1.0:
>   Could not find artifact com.mycom:myapp-core:jar:1.0 in eap
>   (http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all) -> [Help 1]

I followed the guid from [Without using Maven guide](https://developers.openshift.com/servers/tomcat/dependencies.html) *(I created lib folder and added `myapp-core.jar`)* but the same error has occured. So , I removed `myapp-core.jar` dependency declaration from *pom.xml* but class not found errors were occured *(it means my jar file is not include)* .

Can somebody guide me kindly with step by step to solve my problem ? Be happy with helping a noob. Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599270/add-local-jar-to-maven-project-which-will-be-deployed-to-openshift#15601738) also not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few choices for making the dependent module accessible.

1. Use the Maven Install goal to load the dependent module in your local repository.
2. Put the two modules as subdirectories of a parent module.  If the modules are nested in this way, the modules can find each other.  See the layout of the bradleyross/tutorials project  at https://github.com/BradleyRoss/tutorials   (documentation at http://bradleyross.github.io/tutorials/) where tutorials-webapp1 and tutorials-common have the same arrangement.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now I'm ok with your sample project link. Thanks alot indeed. Now I can see my sample website. Have a nice day sir. You save my life.